# Delegates between viewcontrollers in swift

Tags: ios, swift, delegates

I am trying to implement delegates in my app between 2 view controllers to in order to reload tableView data in one of them, but when I press the button nothing happens, I've tested it with breakpoints, am I forgetting something in my implementation?

Sending ViewController

```
     protocol UpdateDelegate {
            func updateExerciseCells()
        }

        class ExerciseVC: UIViewController {


            var delegate:UpdateDelegate?


           @IBAction func saveWorkoutPressed(_ sender: Any) {

                exercise = Exercise(name: exerciseNameInput.text!, weight: weightInput.text!, reps: repsInput.text!, sets: setsInput.text!, difficulty: "")

                WorkoutService.instance.exercises.append(exercise!)


                self.delegate?.updateExerciseCells()

                dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

            }
}
```

Receiving ViewController

```
class WorkoutVC: UIViewController, UpdateDelegate {

    var alert:ExerciseVC = ExerciseVC()




    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        alert.delegate = self
    }

 func updateExerciseCells() {
        //update table
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you set breakpoints at `self.delegate?.updateExerciseCells()` and anywhere inside `func updateExerciseCells() { }`? And if so what is the result? (It's useful with these types of posts to comment in the code about what is happening when you execute..)

Comment: I've set breakpoints at both, the breakpoint hits in the IBAction function, but not in ```updateExerciseCells()```

Comment: So is self.delegate? not nil?

Comment: it is nil in viewDidLoad of exerciseVC

Comment: Is it nil inside the `IBAction saveWorkoutPressed(sender:)` block?

Comment: it is nil inside of the saveWorkoutPressed block

Comment: In this case, `self.delegate?.updateExerciseCells()` will not be called. That is your problem. Make sure `self.delegate?` is not nil, and it will call `saveWorkouPressed()`. If you are able to share the project via github I can take a look. Off today :)

Comment: Do you think it could be because ExerciseVC is page Sheet and not a full page VC?

Comment: Can't say. I'd have to see more of your code. What did you think of the github idea above?

Comment: here's the link: https://github.com/noahbino/databaseProject

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is happening here is that you are creating `ExerciseVC` programatically, but your `Main.storyboard` is creating another one through the segue. So `delegate` is nil on the one created by the segue.

Add this function to your `WorkoutVC`:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let vc = segue.destination as? ExerciseVC {
        vc.delegate = self
    }
}
```

You can delete the `alert` variable in your `WorkoutVC` and any references to it as the one you'll use is already instantiated by `UIStoryBoard`

Answer (score 0):

According to your code you use IBAction method in class ExerciseVC, it means that you have this controller in Storyboard. But you initialize ExerciseVC like

```
var alert:ExerciseVC = ExerciseVC()
```

It is incorrect because in this case IBAction methods are never called. Try to use

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "YourStoryboardName", bundle: nil)
let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "yourViewControllerID")
```

Comment: IBAction is called when the button is pressed